# Laravel and MySql Query Behavior

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have this query:

```
( 
  SELECT a.*, b.* FROM tbl_1 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_2...
)
 UNION ALL
(
  SELECT c.*,c.* FROM tbl_2 
)
```

Both tbl1 and tbl2 contain same column (50 each) names..

So, when I run this query in Mysql Workbench, I get 100 columns but with:

```
DB::select ( the query above )
```

I get 50.. The duplicate columns are removed at Laravel level..

Why is this happening?

Thank You..

Comment: Your code is referring to table aliases that do not exist.  The queries will not work.

Comment: Oh.. Queries work.. This code here is a sample.. Just to keep it short and to the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the columns have the same names.

This is ambiguous, so it is not surprising that they are removed.

There isn't much you can do, except for providing new names for the columns that are unique:

```
select a.*, b.col1 as b_col1, b.col2 as b_col2, . . .
```